# How to pass a value from this.state from one js file to another reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a file and I have defined there a variable called "approve" in this.state{}

```
class cd extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      approve: "",

    };
    this.handleA = this.handleApprove.bind(this);

  }

  handleA(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);

    this.setState({ approve: e.target.value });

  }
  render() {
    const { approve } = this.state;
    const {

    } = this.props;

    console.log(approveState);


    return (
     <Card>
                    <CardHeader title="Name" />
                    <CardContent>
                      <Field
                        name="Name"
                        component={RenderText}
                        label=""

                      />
                    </CardContent>
                  </Card>)
```

I need to pass it to another js file....

how d oi pass the value of approve to this js file

Comment: What is the relation between these two components? Is one an ancestor of the other?

Comment: put some code so, we can understand better .

Comment: added the code..

Comment: If the other js file is not child , use should use React Context, else you can pass it directly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your setup is currently:

```
[component A]
  -> [component B state(approve)]
  -> [component C *wants state(approve)*]
```

then push the state up the component hierarchy and pass it down as a prop. If the children need to be able to change the value, then pass a callback like `setApprove`:

```
[component A state(approve) setApprove]
  -> [component B props(approve, setApprove)]
  -> [component C props(approve, setApprove)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this example state and function passing one component to another component

parent.js

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./child.js";

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "Click"
    };
  }
  update = () => {
    console.log("i am called");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child value={this.state.value} update={this.update} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

child.js

```
import React from "react";

    class Child extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <button onClick={this.props.update}>{this.props.value}</button>;
      }
    }
export default Child;
```